# Setting timer interval based on stopwatch value

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I want my timer interval to be set based on the stopwatch value. Stopwatch calculates the execution time of a function and this execution time should be used for my timer interval.

```
Timer t = new Timer(timercallbackfunc, null, 0, elapsedtime);
```

Please provide some code examples.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
...
Timer t = new Timer(timercallbackfunc, null, 0, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: You forgot to call `stopwatch.Stop()`

Comment: @Schaliasos Why would `stopwatch.Stop()` *need* to be called? It may be desirable to keep it running if it is measuring something that extends beyond the timer call.

Comment: There is no need to call stopwatch.Stop() before calling stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.

Comment: Timer is in main function and timercallbackfunction uses stopwatch to calculate the execution time of function.

Comment: timercallbackfunction(){ Stopwatch stopwatch=new Stopwatch();stopwatch.Start(); Myfunction();stopwatch.Stop();Timespan sw=stopwatch.Elapsed(); Now calling this sw in main(){ Timer timer=new Timer(timercallbackfunction,null,0,sw); ... Is this gonna work??